# Create an array from 2 other arrays

Tags: php

```
$arrayA = Array ( 
                 [0] => 1, 
                 [1] => 2, 
                 [2] => 4 
                )

$arrayB = Array ( 
                 [1] => Dog, 
                 [2] => Cat, 
                 [3] => Cow, 
                 [4] => Duck 
                )
```

How do I create an `$arrayC` that takes the value from the above 2 arrays:

```
$arrayC = Array ( 
                 [1] => Dog, 
                 [2] => Cat, 
                 [4] => Duck 
                )
```

Theoretically, it's something like this:

```
$arrayC = Array ( 
                 [$arrayA[0]] => $arrayB[$arrayA[0]],
                 [$arrayA[1]] => $arrayB[$arrayA[1]],
                 [$arrayA[2]] => $arrayB[$arrayA[2]]
                )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to do something like this :-

```
foreach ($arrayA as $number)
{
  if(isset($arrayB[$number])
  {
    $arrayC[$number] = $arrayB[$number];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this in elegant way without foreach ([Demo](http://codepad.org/JT1T6YGY)):

```
$arrayC = array_intersect_key($arrayB, array_flip($arrayA));
```

See [`array_intersect_key`<sup>*[Docs]*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) and [`array_flip`<sup>*[Docs]*</sup>](http://php.net/array_flip)

Comment: Very nice! Even better than mine.

Comment: +1: Would suggest this solution as well, added a demo and some links.

Answer (score 2):

```
$arrayC = array();
foreach ($arrayA as $key) {
  if (isset($arrayB[$key])) {
     $arrayC[$key] = $arrayB[$key];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to write the foreach loop yourself:

```
//get only the keys that are in both
$arrayA = array_intersect_key(array_fill_keys($arrayA , true), $arrayB);
$arrayB = array_intersect_key($arrayB, $arrayA);

//combine the arrays
$arrayC = array_combine(array_keys($arrayA), $arrayB);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($arrayA as $i => $key) {
    $arrayC[$key] = $arrayB[$arrayA[$i]];
}
```

`$arrayC` will be:

```
Array ( [1] => Dog [2] => Cat [4] => Duck )
```