# Function that checks for keys in array and return array with those keys

Tags: php, arrays, key

I remember that there were function that have such functionality. Unfortunately, I don't remember the name of it. Basically, it did something like...

```
$values = foo(array('x', 'y', 'z'), $_POST);
```

If there are such keys in the array, it does return new array (named `$values`) with only those keys... taken from `$_POST`. If one or more keys aren't in `$_POST`, it simply returns `false`.

Anyone remember something like that or I was just dreaming? Thanks in advice!

Comment: If you suspect such a function exists, just look for it in the [array functions list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856802/create-an-array-from-2-other-arrays/6856965#6856965

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php

Answer (score 0):

I think the function you are looking for is `array_intersect_key()` As of PHP 5.1.0.

> array array_intersect_key ( array $array1 , array $array2 [, array $ ... ] )

Parameters

`array1` - The array with master keys to check.

`array2` - An array to compare keys against.

`array` - A variable list of arrays to compare.

Returns an associative array containing all the entries of array1 which have keys that are present in all arguments.

Answer (score 0):

check out this function array_key_exists

```
<?php

   $search_array = array('first' => 1, 'second' => 4);
   if (array_key_exists('first', $search_array)) 
   {
     echo "The 'first' element is in the array";
   }
?>
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php